# How do we find Associated primes Geometrically?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm reading about primary decomposition from Atiyah and Macdonald's book. One of my friend told me that it is possible to find Associated primes and Primary decomposition geometrically. I tried to found the geometric way in Atiyah and Macdonald's book, but it is not explained in the book. Can someone explain for the following example:

> Let $I=(x^2+xy,y^2-1) \subset k[x,y]$. Find Associated primes and Primary decomposition geometrically.

Comment: Why don't ask your friend for more details?

Comment: @user26857 I asked him,he advised me to read Reid's commutative Algebra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to find the associated primes and primary decompositions geometrically, but this particular example is easy enough since $I$ is a radical ideal (why?) and therefore it is the intersection of its minimal prime ideals, that is, $$I=(X,Y-1)\cap(X,Y+1)\cap(X+1,Y-1)\cap(X-1,Y+1).$$

Comment: I supposed that the characteristic of $k$ is $\ne2$.

Comment: Sorry..  I can see that the mentioned prime are the only associated primes But I'm unable to see why $I$ is radical ?

Comment: @Learner $K[X,Y]/(X(X+Y),Y^2-1)\simeq K[X]/(X^2+X)\times K[X]/(X^2-X)\simeq K^4$ and this is a reduced ring.

Comment: Sorry..How do you get the first isomorphism?

Comment: @Learner From CRT: $(Y-1)$ and $(Y+1)$ are coprime.